how can i make spacemacs copy to system clipboard on wayland?
So i was trying out spacemacs, and honestly its pretty cool. But when i copy something with 'y' , it copies it to a local clipboard, meaning i can only paste it in the same file, and i cant paste external code inside the file. I was also getting this issue on vs code vim keybindings, so now i use zed, as it seem to be the only editor with good vim keybinding that support wayland clipboard handling. But i wanna try using spacemacs, so how can i copy to system clipboard, and paste from system clipboard too?

Okay, a few questions: 1. Do you use non-terminal spacemacs, 2. do you have XWayland installed? 3. if you open emacs -Q and press M-Backspace (it will delete the word buffer.), does the word buffer. appear in the system clipboard? 4. What DE are you using? (if for 1 you use GUI and 3 does work, you can ignore 2nd question).

FTR, I just tested on KDE wayland, and copy/paste works no problem. So it's definitely something on your side.
